# Forward url's to another location

Tags: .htaccess, forwarding

I have a domain that doesn't have a website, but instead I would like to use that domain to forward to url's where I do have websites. Is the .htaccess file the way to go?

For example I have the domain example.com and want to forward differently based on the subdirectory:

www.example.com --> www.test.com

www.example.com/membership --> www.test.com/membership

Comment: Yes, `.htaccess` will work for that. There are some examples in the "related" sidebar on the right of this page. Domain registrars often offer domain redirection, which may be easier for you to configure.

Comment: I just got off the phone with them (1and1.com) and they don't offer much help.

Comment: This might be helpful: http://help.1and1.com/domains-c36931/domain-administration-c79822/domain-destination-c38672/redirectforward-your-domain-a594868.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Apache, you can have this information stored directly in the server configuration.

Documentation here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/remapping.html

You should be able to use any of the examples above directly in a .htaccess file too if that is your preferred method.

It might be better to implement your redirect in the server configuration if it is a permanent move, however a .htaccess file should be fine.

**Edit:** I've added code to add to a .htaccess , the first redirects all traffic to the new domain, the second redirects to the new domain whilst maintaining subdirectory paths.

**Redirect All:**

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.newdomain.com/ [R=301,L]
```

**Maintain Subdirectory Paths:**

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks Aidan. Any help writing the .htaccess rules would be appreciated!

Comment: Also, the 301 reference is "Redirect Permanent", and is more friendly for search engines.

Answer (score 0):

You can bootstrap everything to `index.php?path=$1` using [mod_rewrite](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) and make intelligent decisions there using `header('Location: <URL>');` in case you need to change it later or you have some very specific requirements.

Otherwise, `.htaccess` should be ok. (probably better for simple redirections)

Comment: Jochem can you help with the writing of the .htaccess file. I'm not sure how to write it out. Thanks.

Comment: @Dan See Aidan's answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use .htaccess if you have a server with Apache installed.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com[nc]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.test.com/$1 [r=301]
```

You can also do in similar way on other web servers like nginx or lighttpd.

Rewrite rules are generated from [here](http://www.htaccessredirect.net/).