# Forward one Page to another location in java jsf

Tags: java, jsf, glassfish

I need something Like [Forward url's to another location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21102998/forward-urls-to-another-location) that work with jsf in glassfish not apache , The main problem of me is I have one Web Application That Serv for Android Services and In this application I have Jsf pages for admin panel, after a while we need create Another Web Application That provide WebView, So we have Struc like this :

Https://example.com/App (That show Web Panel for manage the android and web application)

And

Https://example.com/App/Web (That show WebView of our new Application)

In here I need when user enter the Https://example.com/ shows the content of Https://example.com/App/Web but not redirect url!
and stay the page of Https://example.com/.
in docroot of glassfish I have JS and Css file so I can't change the Https://example.com/App/ (App) context to this (/).
Now what can I do for showing the web application in the domain address?

good to know that application is huge in files and xhtml file so I can't re struc the project.
Another subject that good to know is I have only one index.html in App/Web

This is the Address of WebApplication :
https://cattell.ir/App/Web/index.html

Glassfish full platform Version 7.0.3

JDK 17